# How to get all correct values of UICollectionView from Array

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am fetching the api call and gets the data text let's say(Text1 , Text 2 , Text 3) and each texts has its own id (Text1 = 32, Text2 = 33, Text3 = 34). So whenever i select any of the text (Text1 or Text2 or Text3) it stores in array and in the print i can see the id value. But now problem is if i select multiple texts then in print result it does not show correct id. Means at first i select text1 and in print it gives me 32 now i select remaining text so i expecting to get ["32","33","34"] but it gives me ["32", "34"] and if i deselect any text then still it is printing two or three times like this ["32", "34", "32", "32"]

```
class EatTypeCell : UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            if isSelected{
                self.lblTitle.applyStyle(labelFont: UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 10), textColor: UIColor.ColorWhite)
              self.contentView.applyViewStyle(isRound: true, borderColor: UIColor.ColorGray, borderWidth: 0, backGroundColor: UIColor.ColorPink)
            }
            else{
                self.lblTitle.applyStyle(labelFont: UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 10), textColor: UIColor.ColorGray)
                self.contentView.applyViewStyle(isRound: true, borderColor: UIColor.ColorGray, borderWidth: 1, backGroundColor: UIColor.ColorWhite)
            }
        }
    }
        override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.contentView.applyViewStyle(isRound: true, borderColor: UIColor.ColorGray, borderWidth: 1, backGroundColor: UIColor.ColorWhite)
        self.lblTitle.applyStyle(labelFont: UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 10), textColor: UIColor.ColorGray)
    }
}
class OfferVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var colEat: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnFind: ThemeButton!
var arrayMeal : [Meal] = []
var num : [String] = [] 
func setUpView() {
        GFunctions.shared.APICallMenuMeal { (complete, arrayItem) in //API Call
            if complete{
                self.arrayMeal = arrayItem
                self.colEat.reloadData()
            }
        }
self.colEat.delegate = self
        self.colEat.dataSource = self
        self.colEat.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    @IBAction func btnFindTapped(_ sender: ThemeButton) {
            filterMenId = ""
            if let indexPath = self.colEat.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first{
                filterMenId = self.arrayMeal[indexPath.row].id.description
                num.append(filterMenId)
                print(num)// Here printing to see the stored values in array
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear when your button is tapped and in which state the collection is at that moment, so I'd suggest to print `indexPathsForSelectedItems` in order to check what items it actually has when the button is tapped.

Anyway, if you just want to get all selected items values at once then you can simply do this:

```
@IBAction func btnFindTapped(_ sender: ThemeButton) {
    num = self.colEat.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.map { 
        self.arrayMeal[$0.item].id.description 
    }
}
```

And if you want to update your array step by step then I'd suggest to handle it in [collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) and [collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618035-collectionview) respectively:

```
extension OfferVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        num.append(self.arrayMeal[indexPath.item].id.description)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        num.removeAll { $0 == self.arrayMeal[indexPath.item].id.description }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show this in my code because i am a bit beginner in swift

Comment: @MohammedNabil I extended my answer with more code examples